# Django: css document wont load on base html template

Tags: css, django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

I made the following css script inside of my site folder(same place where templates folder is located), but when I run the script, and look at the site, the changes dont show.

I also inspected the css code, and its not finding the file I linked it to, but I'm sure the file is there in the directory I linked. Here is
[The Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNLsw.jpg)

the code for both files:

Users/Docs/Django/src(site folder w/ manage.py)/static/base.css

```
body {
 background-color: lightblue;
 font-family: verdana;
 }
```

Users/Django/src/templates/base.html

```
{% load static %}
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'base.css' %}">
  <title>Coding for Entrepreneurs is doing Try Django</title>
</head>
<body>
{% include 'navbar.html' %}

  {% block content %}
    AAAAAA
  {% endblock %} 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Show related settings.py and urls.py parts.

Answer (score 0):

Im new to Django and I just add the style sheet directly on the html template using < style >  and it works well.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).